# Mysql select day by day

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have table `userMessage` with rows `id`, `userID`, `text` and `date` (timestamp). I want to get statistics on the number of messages for each day. how to write such a sample?

Comment: What kind of database do you need this for?  And do you only want to select for the current day, or all dates, or a range of dates?

Comment: @LukStorms, i want to select for all dates, not only for the current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL will work in MySql

```
SELECT 
CAST(`date` AS DATE) AS MessageDate, 
COUNT(*) AS TotalMessages, 
COUNT(DISTINCT userID) AS TotalUniqueUsers
FROM userMessage
GROUP BY MessageDate
ORDER BY MessageDate DESC
```

You can test it on *db<>fiddle* [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ed75fb8295aa7339422c06e786b9dc8c)

*(Btw, it might be better to use column names that don't look like reserved words.

F.e. instead of `date` use a name like `msgTimestamp`)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the database is, but in SQLite, I have try to run this, it is OK:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%d',yourDateColumnName) as DATE_BY_DAY,count(*) 
  from userMessage 
 group by DATE_BY_DAY;
```

Comment: in mysql i changed  `strftime('%Y-%m-%d',date)` to `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')`, but DATE_BY_DAY is null :c